# W3 Total Cache and Redirects return 200 OK, instead of 301

Tags: wordpress, caching, redirect

When a page is set to be a 301 redirect using Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin and I have page caching enabled (Disk: Enhanced and Basic), I get the page return as 200 OK (just a blank white page and does not redirect) and not 301. Turning off page caching and it redirects fine.

This happens to several sites on the same box. I am assuming there is a config issue that might be the problem.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.